# Using PDO fetch to get an array and using if statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement, pdo

My array would only get a 0 or a 1. I'm using PDO statement for mysql, and this is what I have

```
$result = $fetching -> fetch();
$first_result = $result[0];

if($first_result === 0){
//do something...
}else{
echo "testing";
}
```

I'm always getting the `testing` no matter what, if its 0 or not. I've echoed out the `$first_result[0]` for testing purposes and it will tell me what the value is. So I know that the value will shoot out either 0 or not 0. But when it is 0, it still echos out `testing`.

Help please?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you done a var_dump() to ensure the types match? Remember === compares type and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all try to put `==` not type equivalence. And Second I always use this to check if there any record:

```
$q = $pdo->prepare('Your SQL');
$result = $q->execute($params);
$rows = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!count($rows) || !$result)
{
    echo 'No rows or error';
    // To output error $pdo->errorInfo();
}
else
{
    $el = $row[0];
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: would fetchAll be slow if the database gets extremely large?

Comment: Depends on what do you mean saying extremely large? If you expect really large number of rows, it's a good practice to limit and making partition for your queries. I any case if you want to select all at once, there always would be a hard-ware limitations. So, the partition is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The === is testing for type, pdo will return a string in that case so you are testing an int against a string.

Try:

```
if($first_result === '0'){
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your types are not matching. === matches value and type

> PHP’s === Operator enables you to compare or test variables for both
>   equality and type. Refer below for example.

[Read More...](http://danieldumas.com/php-operators-the-triple-equals-operator.php)